# No Typescript compiler found in your project, analysis of typescript files is aborted

Tags: javascript, typescript, sonarqube

I have configured sonarqube in a VM(Windows Server 2012 R2) which is the build agent for VSTS. Then tried to run code quality check during the build process but is getting the below warning:

```
No Typescript compiler found in your project, analysis of typescript files is aborted.
```

Although the build is continuing, the sonarqube doesn't analyse any TS files. The packages which are aleady installed in the VM:

1. SonarQube version: 6.7.4
2. SonarTS version: 1.1.0.1079
3. Node.js: 0.12.2.0 (I tried installing Node.js 8 and 8+ version. but i was getting error that 0.12.2.0 is not supported and would require 8 or
   8+ even after installing them. So rolled back to the previous form,)
4. TS in the VM: Typescript 1.7.6.0

I referred the thread [https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/releases/tag/1.2.0-RC1 and tried to install the sonar-typescript-plugin-1.2.0.1467.jar](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/releases/tag/1.2.0-RC1%20and%20tried%20to%20install%20the%20sonar-typescript-plugin-1.2.0.1467.jar) , and tried to install the latest .jar file. But i am getting the below error:

```
No main manifest Attribute in D:\sonar-typescript-plugin-1.2.0.1467.jar
```

Any help of the same please?

Comment: Is this question the same as [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/issues/258) reported issue?

Comment: yes, it is. W.r.t that thread, i tried to  install the updated jar file "sonar-typescript-plugin-1.2.0.1467.jar", and  i'm getting the below error:
No main manifest Attritbute in D:\sonar-typescript-plugin-1.2.0.1467.jar. Also opened a new thread  https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/issues/689 but no one answers till now.